Solve the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}$
Recently I saw a differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{y}{x}=0$$ where $x\neq 0$ that is $x\in(-\infty,\infty)-${$0$}
Now this differential equation is literally easy and doable.
The process is $$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{y}{x}=0$$
$$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{y}dy=\frac{1}{x}dx$$
$$\implies \int\frac{1}{y}dy=\int\frac{1}{x}dx+\ln(C)$$
$$\implies \ln|y|=\ln|x|+\ln(C)$$
Now in the book it was mentioned that $\ln|y|=\ln(y)$ and $\ln|x|=\ln(x)$ and the solution was given by
$$\implies \ln(y)-\ln(x)=\ln(C)$$
$$\implies \ln\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=\ln(C)$$
$$\implies \frac{y}{x}=C$$
$$\implies y=xC$$
But here is my main doubt.
How can one say that $\ln(|x|)=\ln(x)$ ?
According to me the solution will be $$\ln(|y|)-\ln(|x|)=\ln(C)$$
$$\implies \ln\left(\frac{|y|}{|x|}\right)=\ln(C)$$
$$\implies \frac{|y|}{|x|}=C$$
$$\implies |y|=C|x|$$
$$\implies \sqrt{y^{2}}=\sqrt{x^{2}}C$$
Squaring both sides we will get
$$\implies y^{2}=x^{2}C_{1}$$
Where $C_{1}=C^{2}$
Please explain me that is my process correct ? Or the book's process is correct ?

The book is wrong.

Your differential equation is not defined at $x=0$. Therefore, either $x \gt 0$ or $x \lt0$ depending on the initial condition.

Yes both of you are correct. Then my process is only correct  ?

Your solution is incomplete. For example, the function $f(x)=\begin{cases} x & x>0\ 2x & x<0 \end{cases}$ is also a solution. As has been observed here, you need to be careful with the domain of the function. In this case, since $x$ can't be $0$, the domain is disconnected and then when one integrates and add an integration constant, one need to address the fact that the constant may not be the same in each connected component of the domain.

I have edited my question. But if something is still missing then please edit my question @jjagmath. Actually in the book the full conditions are not at all mentioned.

Your solution is still missing the example I gave. Another missing solution is  $y(x)=0$, which is not part of your solution because $C$ can't be $0$ since you used $\ln(C)$.

$|y|=C|x|$ and $y=Cx$ are the same sets of solutions, if you take into account that this only defines a solution on $x < 0$ or $x > 0$, and the constants need to be chosen independently to get a solution on the whole domain.

Yes you are correct @OleksandrKulkov. But my main doubt is that how can I consider $|x|=x$ ? We all know that $|x|\neq x$ for $x<0$

$|x|=x$ and $\ln |x| = \ln x$ is only true for $x > 0$, yes. With $x < 0$, real logarithm is undefined.

The book is not correct.
To solve the problem correctly, you should suppose that $x \neq 0$ as otherwise the differential equation is not defined.
On your side, you're right up to $\lvert y \rvert = \lvert x \rvert C$. Your following implications are also correct but do not lead to a proper definition of $y$.
A maximal solution is indeed $y = Ax$, but is only defined for $x \gt 0$ or $x \lt 0$ as $x = 0$ is not allowed in the initial differential equation.
Note (which could be the "moral of your question"): a function is not only an equation but also a domain (and a codomain)!

Since the domain here is defined as $\mathbb R \setminus {0}$, I think the solution on the full domain would be a combination of $y = A x$ for $x < 0$ and $y = B x$ for $x > 0$ with possibly distinct $A$ and $B$. I don't really see where the $A \neq 0$ come from though? $y=0$ seems to be a valid solution.

@OleksandrKulkov Usually, maximal solutions are an essential notion for differential equations. A maximal solution is defined on an interval. And $\mathbb R \setminus {0}$ is not an interval. However, I agree that $A \neq 0$ is unnecessary, and I will update my answer accordingly.
